# How to manipulate Linux command output using Python

Tags: python, linux

I'm really struggling to understand how to best manipulate Linux command output using Python and would be grateful for any help or pointers.

The below command returns a list of all the printers by name installed on a CUPS server:

```
lpstat -v | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/://g'
PRINTER1
PRINTER2
PRINTER5
PRINTER10
...
```

However I don't know the best way to achieve this using Python.

I can get the full output from just the `lpstat` command and store it in a variable with:

```
installed_printers = subprocess.check_output(["lpstat", "-v"]).decode('utf-8')
```

However I don't really know the best way to get, say, just the printer name in the 3rd column? Or the other thing I want to do is get a list of the printer name along with just the IP and then put it in a dataframe. Which from just the command line, I can get with:

```
# lpstat -v | awk '{sub(":", "", $3) sub("ipp://", "", $4) sub("/ipp/print", "", $4); print $3 ", "  $4}'
```

Any help achieving this with python would be greatly appreciated.

---

Updated: 08/08/23

Thanks for all the responses I've got here - they've already helped me a lot. One comment suggested I broke the tasks into steps to better define the question.

First I get a Google Sheets spreadsheet with all the printer information and put it into a dataframe. After messing around with that a bit I'm left with a list of printer name and corresponding IP.

```
another_list = df5.values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['SEHMFD001', '10.121.120.231'],
 ['SEHMFD003', '10.121.120.233'],
 ['SEHMFD002', '10.121.120.62'],
 ['LONMFD001', '10.110.240.231'],
 ...
 ['STAPRT004', '10.110.16.231'],
 ['STAMFD006', '10.130.0.231'],
 ['WHAMFD001', '10.130.12.231'],
 ['WHAMFD002', '10.130.14.231'],
 ['WHAMFD003', '10.130.13.231']]
```

Then I use that to build the following commands:

```
printers_to_install = []

for entry in another_list:
    case = "lpadmin -p " + entry[0] + " -E -v ipp://" + entry[1] + "/ipp/print -m everywhere"
    printers_to_install.append(case)
```

I then end up with a list of commands I want to run:

```
['lpadmin -p SEHMFD001 -E -v ipp://10.121.120.231/ipp/print -m everywhere',
 'lpadmin -p SEHMFD003 -E -v ipp://10.121.120.233/ipp/print -m everywhere',
...
'lpadmin -p WHAMFD001 -E -v ipp://10.130.12.231/ipp/print -m everywhere',
 'lpadmin -p WHAMFD002 -E -v ipp://10.130.14.231/ipp/print -m everywhere',
 'lpadmin -p WHAMFD003 -E -v ipp://10.130.13.231/ipp/print -m everywhere']
```

I was hoping to put those into a loop and use `subprocess` to execute each one. However using `subprocess` to execute one long line does not seem to work:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["lpadmin -p SEHMFD001 -E -v ipp://10.121.120.231/ipp/print -m everywhere"])

...

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lpadmin -p SEHMFD001 -E -v ipp://10.121.120.231/ipp/print -m everywhere'
```

I can make the command work if I split the command up like so:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["lpadmin", "-p", "SEHMFD001", "-E", "-v", "ipp://10.121.120.231/ipp/print", "-m", "everywhere"])
```

But how can I do this with programmatically and still loop through all the commands I want to execute in the `printers_to_install` list?

Comment: However you want to. You can use `string.split()` operations, or `re` operations... Python gives you _lots_ of choices, and which to use really comes down to opinion/preference; without specific criteria to judge options against each other, there's no such thing as "best".

Comment: `print('\n'.join([ line.split('\t')[2].replace(':', '') for line in installed_printers.strip().split('\n')]))` is one very rough, untested example of one of the _many_ ways to do this.

Comment: As for your larger awk script -- which _specific_ part of that script do you need help translating? What narrow, specific technical problem do you get stuck on? "How do I replace one string with another in Python?" is a very narrow and specific question that's surely already in our knowledgebase; "how do I iterate over content line-by-line in Python?" is another. Break down the task into steps, try to do each step on its own, and if you get stuck then you can specify the specific place you got stuck at to have a better-defined question.

Comment: Can you post the output of `lpstat -v` that you are processing? Instead of using awk and sed, one would likely just do string processing in python. Parsing command output that isn't specifically created for machine reading can be difficult. I noticed [`pycups`](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/pycups), a python binding to `libcups` seems to be active. It would be worth exploring. Going through the API instead of one of the utilities may be the most robust solutions.

Comment: For the question in the title: I like writing filters (when possible), so that they can interact using stdin and stdout just like a typical shell tool. This question sounds like a command that might need to be performed once, in which case I would have no problem piping whatever output to a text file, optionally manually reformatting it for convenience, and then parsing it in python (if necessary) to do whatever it is that I'm trying to do. I'll also note that you could call the entire piped command that you wrote from python as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```py
import sys

list_of_lists = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    new_list = [elem for elem in line.split()]
    list_of_lists.append(new_list)

print(list_of_lists)
```

The split is there in case your lines have spaces. Note the output looks something like this

```
[['PRINTER1'], ['PRINTER2'], ['PRINTER3']]
```

to use it just pipe the output of the command as follows

```
lpstat -v | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/://g' | python script.py
```